# Cart implimentation for eCommerce/Shopping app

Tags: objective-c, e-commerce

I have to make a cart for my app, but I don't know the best way to implement it.
I'm thinking about using `NSMutableArray`, but I am not sure if it's the best way to to this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try an NSMutableOrderedSet.

Here's what they say in the AppleDocumentation:

> "You can use ordered sets as an alternative to arrays when the order
>   of elements is important and performance in testing whether an object
>   is contained in the set is a consideration— testing for membership of
>   an array is slower than testing for membership of a set."

Checking if a certain product is already in the cart can be difficult and inefficient - using an NSMutableOrderedSet saves you that trouble. It's much like an NSMutableArray but more efficient for this function.

Answer (score 0):

Although it depends on the size of your cart, arrays are not the best option if you intend to effectively search/fetch the cart contents through ID tag or something. 
A NSDictionary would be a better option.

Comment: Yeah, but the fact is that im not allow to search the cart or whatelse. Only delete a item.

Comment: If your cart is relatively small you can use an NSArray. And for finding a specific object you can use `- (NSIndexSet *)indexesOfObjectsWithOptions:(NSEnumerationOptions)opts passingTest:(BOOL (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))predicate
` method from NSArray to query your cart.